# Writing a java object to a file using SnakeYaml - List of inner objects are not writen out when using Yaml.dump()

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I am having trouble writing out a java object to a yml file using SnakeYaml. I have setup a spring boot project with a simple application.yml that I convert to a set of java objects. In the real application some objects get added and when the application is done I want to write out the new application.yml.

The input application.yml looks like this:

```
sample:
  name: toyota
  cars:
     - model: prius
       colour: silver
     - model: avensis
       colour: red
```

The java object that maps this application.yml:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="sample")
public class Config {

    private String name;
    private final List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }
}
```

And the sample class that writes out the yaml:

```
@Component
public class Example {

    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        yaml.dump(config, writer);      
        System.out.println(writer.toString());          
    }
}
```

The output is just: `name: toyota` (ommitted some yaml settings that also get writen out). However I want the output to be exactly the same as the input:

```
sample:
  name: toyota
  cars:
     - model: prius
       colour: silver
     - model: avensis
       colour: red
```

Is there a way to do this?

### EDIT:

User flyx correctly pointed out the following [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections).

My adjusted code:

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Config.class);
TypeDescription configDescription = new TypeDescription(Config.class);
configDescription.putListPropertyType("cars", Car.class);
constructor.addTypeDescription(configDescription);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
yaml.dump(config, writer);      
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Gives the following output:

```
$$beanFactory: !!org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
  allowBeanDefinitionOverriding: true
  allowEagerClassLoading: true
  autowireCandidateResolver: !!org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver {}
  beanClassLoader: !!sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader {}
  beanExpressionResolver: !!org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver {}
  cacheBeanMetadata: true
  conversionService: null
  dependencyComparator: !!org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator {}
  parentBeanFactory: null
  serializationId: application
  tempClassLoader: null
  typeConverter: !!org.springframework.beans.SimpleTypeConverter {conversionService: null}
name: toyota
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an explicit setter on the list of Car, the list will not be printed.

After changing:

```
private final List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}
```

To this:

```
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}
public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}
```

The code works.

Answer (score 2):

SnakeYAML cannot get the element type of `List` at runtime because of type erasure. The documentation has an [example](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections) of what you need to do.

Something like this should work:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init(){
    Constructor c = new Constructor(Config.class);
    TypeDescription configD = new TypeDescription(Config.class);
    configD.putListPropertyType("cars", Car.class);
    c.addTypeDescription(configD);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(c);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    yaml.dump(config, writer);      
    System.out.println(writer.toString());          
}
```

Comment: Your answer is useful thank you. However still only `name: toyota` gets printed. I will update the question with your suggestion.